# special hex characters getting messed up in passing variable from Applescript to shell

Tags: bash, shell, applescript

I'm trying to use the CSV to spotify playlist converter at http://www.playlist-converter.net/tutorial/api

It simply takes a URL formed like:

```
 http://www.playlist-converter.net/#/freetext=The%20Trance%20Is%20The%20Motion%20-%20Static-X%0ABled%20For%20Days%20-%20Static-X
```

But, I'm really getting stuck on the '#' character because if I try to escape it with \ as you would directly in bash, then the Applescript compile fails; and every other attempt I've made passes it as %23 as in

```
 http://www.playlist-converter.net/%23/freetext...etc.
```

which will not load properly at the website.

Any suggestions for how to pass the literal hash from the Applescript 'do shell script' command to a browser in tact?

Comment: I don't use Spotify, so I can test it, however I have no problem passing the URL shown in the OP intact without changing the `#` in a `do shell script` _command_. Of course it may have to do with the explicit `do shell script` _command_ I tested with. That said, you should have included the exact _code_ that causing the failure and if you what help debugging code then your question should conform to [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). That said, if the URL is set as a _variable_, e.g. `theURL` try using: `the quoted form of theURL`

Comment: thanks. that first bit of code should return the expected results at playllist-converter.net  there's no need to use spotify or have an account. the website should return a tracklist with two records. that's all I'm after. but, I will edit in the actual applescript do shell command...hold tight

Comment: In your comment you said "that first bit of code should return the expected results..." but there is absolutely no AppleScript code showing the _code_ you used to generate the error!

Comment: I have no problem opening the URL you show in the OP in a Browser, either with a `do shell script` _command_ or scripting a Browser directly. **Using** `set theURL to "http://www.playlist-converter.net/#/freetext=The%20Trance%20Is%20The%20Motion%20-%20Static-X%0ABled%20For%20Days%20-%20Static-X"` **and** `do shell script "open " & theURL` **or** `tell application "Safari" to open location theURL` and both of these open the URL properly formed.

Comment: You should definitely add your code here

Answer (score -2):

Well, the database on the server I was using to pull my data from took a dump. So, sorry for going dark. Not only could I not pull any more test data--I needed to get it back going again.

And, as usual taking a break gave me some needed perspective.

my issue was not having a grasp of when shell did NOT URL encode and when applescript DID.

On the off chance this may help  someone, here's my complete issue and resolution.

So, my initial setup is:

I have a local tab-delim text file created with a CURL command, created like:

```
 song 1 /t artist 1 LF
 song 2 /t artist 2 LF
 .
 .
 .etc
```

I need to read these in to my Applescript and pass them ultimately to a URL encoded text string like

> http://www.playlist-converter.net/#/freetext=song%201%20-%20artist%201%0Asong%202%20-%20artist%202

So, first thing I tackled was replacing the LF with CR with Applescript of

```
 do shell script "cp " & posixpathoffile & " " & posixppathoftempfile & " tr '\n' '\r' < " & posixpathoftempfile & " > " & posixpathoffile & ""
```

But, that wasn't nearly everything. Problem is doing everything in shell. I could continue stripping characters and replacing with AWK commands. But, simply reading the original file in shell stripped out the /t tab characters. So, I was forced from here out  to grep the file in to an applescript variable and do all the find/replace with Applescript text item delimiters. So:

```
 set theHtml to do shell script "grep -U $'\\x0' " & posixpathoffile & ""
```

Brings the file with the apple carriage returns in as variable theHTML.  And from  here I use a standard find/replace Applescript function to:

```
 replace all spaces with "%20" as text
 replace all carriage returns with "%0A" as text
 replace all forward slash characters with "and" (it didnt seem to affect 
 the song title or artist)
```

Of course, none of this is useful passed to a simple "do shell script 'open -a Safari 'url'" command. All of my carefully encoded text gets mangled. So, I concatenate the first part of the url with the massaged content and open the page with Safari like

```
 tell application "Safari"
activate
tell window 1
    set current tab to (make new tab with properties {URL:theURL})
end tell
 end tell
```

I hope all of that was as good for you as it was for me. Now, i get to port all of this to Xcode Applescript Obj-C. Wish me luck. And, again my apologies for abandoning my thread.